# Mysql return joined table as sub-array

Tags: php, mysql

I'm using my mysqli query as JSON output.

This is my query:

```
    $sql = "SELECT p.*,comments.*,COUNT(comments.id) AS numComments FROM people AS p
LEFT JOIN comments ON comments.people_id = p.id
 WHERE p.name LIKE '%".$data."%'";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        $myArray[] = $row;
    }
    echo json_encode($myArray);
} else {
    echo 0;
}
```

What I want to do, is to group all the person comments and place it under the person data. for example:

The desired output is that I will be able to access the comments not directly from the query, but from the person itself.

**for example:**
`echo $person['comment'][0]['content']`

Currently, I access it like any of the query data..

`echo $person['content']`

**JSON OUTPUT:**

[image]

As you can see, the person data and the comment data is mixed in the same array. I want the comments to have an array of their own.

Any ideas?

**Edit:** Seem like I have problem with the query. it returns only the first comment!

Comment: This query doesn't make much sense to me. If you like, consider following this simple two-step course of action: 1. If you have not already done so, provide proper CREATE and INSERT statements (and/or an sqlfiddle) so that we can more easily replicate the problem. 2. If you have not already done so, provide a desired result set that corresponds with the information provided in step 1.

Comment: And doesn't this duplicate your previous question.

Comment: Hey @Strawberry, I added a json output of my current output. As you can see, the person data and the comment data is mixed in the same array. I want the comments to have an array of their own. And no, its not duplicate, the other question is answered and this one is different

Comment: Not sure why you're showing me json data.

Comment: @TheUnreal hey, the query will return all the data in a single array, you need to differentiate with the another way like setting them in the other key, and unset from the actual array.

Answer (score 0):

You need so-called eager loading for this task. It will involve two queries, but it will be way better than one.

You have to select your people first, then get people ids and query comments table for the comments. And finally you will have to combine the two arrays together.

I will use PDO as it will take 5 times less code to write, [thanks to some neat PDO features](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo#fetchall).

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM people WHERE name LIKE ?");
$stmt->execute(["%$data%"]);
$people = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_UNIQUE);

$ids  = array_keys($people);
$in   = str_repeat('?,', count($ids) - 1) . '?';
$stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT people_id, * FROM comments WHERE people_id IN ($in)");
$stmt->execute($ids);
$comments = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_GROUP);

foreach($people as $id=>$row)
{
    $row['comments'] = $comments[$id];
    $people[$id] = $row;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, but the output is really strange and not correct.. Assuming I have 1 person and 2 comments: http://i.imgur.com/3Z9Jqpl.png - it Shows all the comments in one array item, mixed, with some unknown fields

Comment: set PDO::FETCH_ASSOC as a default fetch mode.

Comment: Thanks, now it's well-organized, but it shows only one comment each person

Comment: sorry I forgot one important thing, fixed now

Comment: All comments are `null` now :S If I'm right, you just added `people_id` in the query, but it's already included in the `*`, means you tried to select it twice

Comment: i's no harm to select it twice. The code should work now. if it returns null than you are doing something wrong.

Comment: Doesn't look like lazy loading to me.

Comment: @TheUnreal you made default mode FETCH_OBJ, not ASSOC as I told you

Comment: @JimmyT. thank you for the correction, it's eager loading indeed.

Comment: Sorry. But the code works if the edited `people_id` is after the `*` this way: `SELECT *,people_id FROM comments WHERE people_id IN ($in)` but the output is still same - one comment for each person. Also, in your code there is `$db` variable and `$conn` variable. I assumed they are supposed to be the same (`$conn`)

Comment: @TheUnreal people_id should be first selected column

Comment: Then why do I get `Undefined offset: 1 ` `Undefined offset: 3 `(The people IDS) and null comments? I'm sure there is a little mistake there causes this errors with the array index..